# Concat query in php with mysql (PDO object)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query from filters param:

```
select * from table WHERE x= :x '{$this->getQuery()}'

function getQuery()
{
  $query = "";
  if ($this->y != "")
    $query ="and y =:y";

  return $query;
}
```

But sometimes when I got empty params from "Y" from the request  I removed the line " and y =:y"  and the query will be:

```
select * from table WHERE x= :x
```

the problem is that i m using . PDO->bind(:y)
and when the query is empty the bind is not working and throw the following error:

```
 Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  have to check the condition when you are binding params .

```
if($this->getQuery()!=''){
     PDO->bind(':y',$val_y);
}
```